# Build a Zend Form to edit a custom Zend Config ini file

Tags: forms, zend-framework, frameworks

I´m trying to make a form to be able to edit a custom config.ini file with some custom settings, I´m trying to do this dynamically, so if i add another line to the config file, it shows on the edit form, or more precisely , i will be using this with a extension like system, where new extensions can add lines in this config.ini file. But, i´m having a hard time with the field names, so for en config file like this:

```
[production]

db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
db.params.host = "localhost"
db.params.username = "user"
db.params.password = "123456"
db.params.dbname = "zend"
```

I need to have the respective fields for each param, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="db[adapter]"/>
<input type="text" name="db[params][host]"/>
<input type="text" name="db[params][username]"/>
<input type="text" name="db[params][password]"/>
<input type="text" name="db[params][dbname]"/>
```

So what would be the easiest way of building this form automatically?

I´ve created a custom Zend_Form, and in this form, a get the config file with Zend_Config,
and loop trough the settings creating a text field for each param, but i like the names to follow the same pattern as the ini file, like in the example above, but all i can get is something like:

```
<input type="text" name="params[host]"/>
<input type="text" name="params[username]"/>
<input type="text" name="params[password]"/>
<input type="text" name="params[dbname]"/>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: To understand the question here. You need help with building a Zend Form where the input fields are named according the the paramets name in your config file?

Comment: Yep, that`s is it, so if i add new lines in the config file it will automaticly show up in the config edit page where the form is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Zend_form so I'm not the right person to answer, but since I've done something similar where I can change the config from inside my application I'm giving it a shot anyway. Personally I would do this in a view-helper and generate the html-form directly without using Zend_form, but if you want to use Zend_form, Zend_sub_form seems the way to go. I know that the below code isn't completely right, bit it should lead you a bit on the way at lest.

```
/**
* The action
*/

public function configAction(){
    //get the zend config from file or from registry and cast it as an array
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
    $config = $config->toArray

    //create the form and a new subform for each part of the config array
    $form = new Zend_Form();
    foreach ($config as $key=>value){
        $form = self::generateSubForm($key, $value, $form);
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}

/**
* Generates all subforms
*/
private function generateSubForm($key, $value, $form){
    //generate a subform for this key if needed
    if(!is_object($form->getSubForm($key)){
        $$key = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $form->addSubForm($$key, $key);
    } else {
        $$key = $form->getSubForm($key);
    }
    //if the value is an array, we must go deeper
    //Else we create a textelement and go on the next one
    if(is_array($value){
        $form = self::generateSubForm($key, $value, $form->getSubForm($key));
    } else{
        $form->getSubForm($key)->addElement('text', 'value');
        $form->getSubForm($key)->$key->setValue($value);
    }

    return $form;
}
```

This should generate a form that looks something like this

```
<input type="text" name="phpSettings[date][timezone][value]" value="Europe/Stockholm">
<input type="text" name="phpSettings[display_startup_errors][value]" value="0">
<input type="text" name="phpSettings[display_errors][value]" value="0">
```

from a config that looks like this

> phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/Stockholm"
>
> phpSettings.display_startup_errors              = 0
>
> phpSettings.display_errors                      = 0